# Keep Sesion Alive Cloudscraper

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, cloudflare

I am making a script with cloudscraper and bs4, when I want to login the following code works perfectly

```
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
print("Iniciando sesion")
startTime = time.time()
site = scraper.get("https://www.innvictus.com/login")
bs_content = bs(site.content, "html.parser")
token = bs_content.find("input", {"name":"g-recaptcha-action"})["value"]
login_data = {"j_username":"torrebz@gmail.com","j_password":"Sep*2020", "g-recaptcha-action":token}
pag = scraper.post("https://www.innvictus.com/login",login_data)
if pag.status_code != 200:
    print("Fail")
else:
    print(pag.status_code)
    print("ok "+pag.url)
```

But when I make another request, the session does not stay active.
What I can do?
I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use rotating ips(Proxies)